# How to mount a partition on the root directory (for example /data)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, mount

I am installing Ubuntu on my empty hard drive and I would like to have a separate partition on which I would store my data, like movies, music, documents, etc.

I don't like the idea of putting those files in `/home/user` directory because I would have multiple users on my computer and I want them all to easily access those files. I might also have multiple operating systems on my computer.

Now, the idea is, I would like that partition to be mounted on something like `/data` , instead of `/media/data`.

Is that safe, and how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what should prevent you from mounting that partition just under root. The command would be `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /data`, where `/dev/sda1` is the partition. Unmount via `sudo umount /data`.

To mount on startup add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sda1    /data    <partition type>    defaults    0    0
```

Comment: I thought so. Thanks. Just one more thing, how to make it mount on startup?

Comment: @dac - Take a look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions). Edit: Oh... er... Just saw that alnkpa already answered that...